# Saving Data to Variable With Different Script File Unity C#

Tags: c#, class, variables

Iam confused saving data to variable with different script file.

For Example :

File player.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class player : MonoBehaviour {
    public int coin = 1000;
}
```

File levelupstorage1raw.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Linq;

public class levelUpStorage1Raw : MonoBehaviour {

    public player Player;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void OnClickWood () {
          Player.coin = Player.coin + 1000;
    }
}
```

In this script player.cs :

```
public class player : MonoBehaviour {
        public int coin = 1000;
    }
```

I have inisial the coin = 1000, this mean int coin have 1000.

In Other script file levelupstorage1raw.cs :

```
    public player Player;
    // Use this for initialization

    public void OnClickWood () {
          Player.coin = Player.coin + 1000;
    }
```

I have add more coin 1000 to Player.coin.

Now my question is : where the Player.coin 1000 is save ? is it save to it own file variable Player.coin or

is it save to player.cs file variable coin ?

If it save to player.cs file variable coin then variable coin now should have 2000.

Comment: That's not how variables work. The variable values are stored in RAM and the changes you made will only be in memory till the program is running. When the game is started, `coin` is initialized to `1000`. When you change `Player.coin`, those changes will only be reflected till the game is running. When `OnClickWood` is called, `1000` is added to `Player.coin`, but these changes will not persist after the game is stopped.

Comment: Hi @EvilTak, so if i run the game and onClickWood is called. How much value in player.cs coin ?

Comment: The value in the file won't change. Only the value in the object `Player` will change. If you create another `player Player2`, `Player2.coin` will be 1000 only. I recommend that you read up and take tutorials on C# programming and OOP.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have to learn a bit more about programming. Try looking for tutorials online.

Regarding your question, if I simplify things a bit to give you an idea:

A variable is something that can change. What is written in your Player.cs file is the default value, the one it will have when starting the program. When you write `Player.coin = Player.coin + 1000;`, the **variable value** changes, so `Player.coin` is now 2000.

At this point the first value (1000) is lost because the variable in your program has been set to 2000. **But this has nothing to do with the file.**

When you run your program, your file has already been transformed to a program. The file with the code is just there to tell the computer how to create the program, **but it won't be modified** when you run the program.

I hope this helps you understand what happens in your example. I still thing you should look for tutorials. Even basic stuff will be really difficult to achieve if you don't know the basics